# A.C.T vs Filipino martial arts

Tags: knife-fighting, kali

What is the difference between [A.C.T.](http://a-c-t.co.il/) (Armed Combat and Tactics) and other Filipino martial arts? What is the emphasis in A.C.T?

Comment: This question shows no prior research whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are [basically unrelated](http://a-c-t.co.il/about-act/). A.C.T. is an Israeli style that's a mix of "[Kendo and Arnis, sport fencing and Silat, Kenjutsu and Aikido, Systema and Naginata-jutsu, Jo-do and Ninjutsu, Kobudo and Wing Chun, Bagua and Dos Manos, Russian knife systems and 19-th century Saber fighting styles to mention a few](http://a-c-t.co.il/how-we-train/)" according to their site.

As regards an emphasis, it looks like they have a combination of drills and free-sparring with their main selling point being their simulation system, which they claim allows free-sparring with weapons in a way which is realistic, but avoids injury.